# Can I work while upgrading?

Tags: upgrade

As the title says, I want to upgrade Ubuntu to 11.10 but I must keep working my whole day. I don't mind a couple of reboots, but I need to work my day. Can I still fully work while it upgrades or does it blocks the system?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say no. The upgrader itself says you shouldn't do work while upgrading a system.

With that being said, I've done all sorts of things - normal word processing, compiling things (that was stupid) and web browsing (just to name a few), the only thing that has given me problems has been compiling things while doing an upgrade.

However, to be on the safe side, don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

It's just like doing your regular updates. You can keep working but might have to restart a few times. Better still, just to remain safe, make a backup of all the work you have done and also all the work you'll be doing during the updates frequently.

Answer (score 2):

When you upgrade & after backing up your current data, you'll see a status window showing the steps of the upgrade, labelled 'distribution upgrade' or something like that. In that window, Ubuntu will check off each step of progress as they are completed:

Preparing to upgrade

Getting new packages

Installing the upgrades

Cleaning up

Restarting the computer

It is near the "Restarting the Computer" phase that Ubuntu wil reboot into the 11.10 release & all unsaved data will be lost.

I would personally wait until you have a a spare hour or two to upgrade to prevent any possible loss of data or interruption from work.